# Mongodb run $in on an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to do a simple query, which is based on array of objects. `fieldA` is an array of objects and my query looks something like this

```
const books = [
  {name: 'LOTR', author: 'J.R Tolkien'},
  {name: 'HP', author: 'JK. Rowling'},
  {name: 'Witcher', author: 'A. Sapkowski'}
];

const exists = await Book.exists({ fieldA: { $in: books } });
```

I am trying to see if the books in `books` array exist in database by implementing a search on `fieldA` which is an array of objects. The problem is that `$in` seems to take only one entity and it always returns false this way. Is there any way i can use `$in` but on array of objects?

Comment: Could you please add one doc that shows what `fieldA` looks like?  Also: are you in general trying to match *any* book in the `books` array to the array that is `fieldA`?  If so, what fields inside `fieldA` do you want to match against the `books` array?  All fields?   Exact and only `name` + `author` (driven by the shape of the `books` data)?    Any `name` or any `author?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We achieve many-to-many matching using `$setIntersection` instead of `$in`.

Assume that `fieldA` has a shape similar to these as we might see in collection `foo`:

```js
[
    {fieldA: [
        {name: 'LOTR', author: 'J.R Tolkien'},
        {name: 'LOTR', author: 'J.R Tolkien'}, // dupes treated as one in $setIntersection; see below        
        {name: 'The Prize', author: 'Daniel Someone'},
        {name: 'Corn', author: 'Dave'},
        {name: 'More Corn', author: 'Dave'},
        {name: 'HP', author: 'JK. Rowling'}
    ]},
    {fieldA: [
        {name: 'Dune', author: 'Herbert'},
        {name: 'HP', author: 'JK. Rowling'},
        {name: 'NOT Witcher', author: 'A. Sapkowski'}, // wrong name; no match
        {name: 'LOTR', author: 'NOT J.R Tolkien'} // wrong author; no match                         
    ]},
    {fieldA: []}, // empty array
    {yada: "nope"} // this doc has NO fieldA!
]
```

This agg pipeline:

```js
var books = [
    {name: 'LOTR', author: 'J.R Tolkien'},
    {name: 'HP', author: 'JK. Rowling'},
    {name: 'Witcher', author: 'A. Sapkowski'}
];

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {X: {$setIntersection: [ "$fieldA", books ]} }},
    {$addFields: {nX: {$size: {$ifNull:["$X",[] ]}} }}
]);
```

yields this output:

```js
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "X" : [
        {
            "name" : "HP",
            "author" : "JK. Rowling"
        },
        {
            "name" : "LOTR",
            "author" : "J.R Tolkien"
        }
    ],
    "nX" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "X" : [
        {
            "name" : "HP",
            "author" : "JK. Rowling"
        }
    ],
    "nX" : 1
}
{ "_id" : 2, "X" : [ ], "nX" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 3, "X" : null, "nX" : 0 }
```

**VERY IMPORTANT CAVEAT:**  For `$setIntersection` involving arrays of objects -- not scalars -- to work as intended, the order of the fields in the objects as returned by MongoDB must match the order of those in the objects in `books` array; in this case `name` must precede `author`.  Swapping the order will cause a mismatch.  To defend against this, you can force the desired order of fields (ostensibly the same order as constructed in the calling query i.e. the order seen in `books`) in each doc of array `fieldA` by running `fieldA` through a `$map`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {X: {$setIntersection: [
        {$map: {
        input: "$fieldA",
            as: "z",
            in: {name: "$$z.name", author: "$$z.author"}
        }},
    books ]} }},

    {$match: {$expr: {$gt:[{$size: {$ifNull:["$X",[] ]}}, 0]}} }
]);
```

Note also that we show how to filter out those docs with no intersections by filtering out zero-length arrays.
The `$ifNull` ensures that `$size` is passed an array (even one of zero length) because docs with no `fieldA` will consider `fieldA` to be `null` and that will produce an error in `$size`.